# Will installing Ubuntu 18.04 remove existing Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 18.04

When we install Ubuntu 18.04 in a laptop which already have Ubuntu 14.04 as well as  Windows 10. So,my doubt is, when we install 18.04, will the already existing Ubuntu 14.04 will get removed?

Comment: Yes & No depending on option you use.  If you select 'erase & install' it'll wipe both Ubuntu & w10 (as you told it to), if you select 'replace' it'll replace your 14.04 with 18.04.  Backup regardless, and I usually use 'something else' so I have more control (can select no-format for example) so it'll wipe system directories, and restore my old programs [if from Ubuntu repos] & not-touch my data; but I'd still backup even using this).  Your selections control what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes & No depending on option you use.

[image: 18.04 install - allocate drive space] If you select 'erase & install' it'll wipe both Ubuntu & w10 (as you told it to).

In the example (from picture I show it does not detect any OSes, but in your case it should detect some and I'd expect it to offer a 'replace' option. If you select 'replace' it'll replace your 14.04 with 18.04. Backup regardless

Myself I usually use 'something else' so I have more control (allowing me to select no-format for example thus avoiding loosing my data) which causes the installer to  wipe system directories, install new Ubuntu and then restore my old programs [*if from Ubuntu repos*] leaving my data in-tack.  I would of course still backup any data important to you.

Your selections control what it does.

*Picture from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5  (page 5 of install tutorial), use #0 to view from the start*